# "This JSX tag's 'children' prop expects a single child of type 'ReactNode'" error when inserting JS

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript

So I have this piece that based on the `showHistory` boolean should show a piece of text.

```
{props.showHistory && <Typography variant="body1">Your previous score was:  </Typography>}
```

But when I want to add a variable like this:

```
{props.showHistory && <Typography variant="body1">Your previous score was: {props.lastScore} </Typography>}
```

It gives me the error "This JSX tag's 'children' prop expects a single child of type 'ReactNode', but multiple children were provided.ts(2746)". I could come up with a work-around I think, but I want to understand what exactly goes wrong here and how to fix it.

Comment: Is `props.lastScore` a string/number or another component?

Comment: It is of type "Number | "none"". I added ".toString()" to it just now and now it works, but I'm curious to learn why it raised the error it did.